# show a html page as a pop up page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a popup page that I want to show it when I clic on this button:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
                
                        function open_infos()
                        {
                                width = 600;
                                height = 400;
                                if(window.innerWidth)
                                {
                                        var left = (window.innerWidth-width)/2;
                                        var top = (window.innerHeight-height)/2;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        var left = (document.body.clientWidth-width)/2;
                                        var top = (document.body.clientHeight-height)/2;
                                }   
                                window.open('app.livarticles','articles','menubar=no, scrollbars=no, top='+top+', left='+left+', width='+width+', height='+height+'');
                                console.log("error...")
                        }
                
                </script>
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn btn-icon"> 
        <a onclick="javascript:open_infos();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="xxxxxx">
            <img src="img\10536.png" class="m-b-xs w-xs">
</a> 
    </div></div>
```

I work with AngularJS,this is Routing file,config.router.js:

```js
.state('app.livarticles', {
                   url: '/livraison/article',
     templateUrl: 'tpl/livarticles.html'
              })
```

but the page doesn't show in the pop up page,any idea pleaze and thanks
update:
when I put the URL manually in the script,this is what I get:

```js
 window.open('tpl/livarticles.html',.........
```

[image]

Comment: So where does it show then?

Comment: Hi  @GolezTrol it shows  Error 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.livarticles` isn't a proper url. It should be something like this:

```
 window.open('http://thesite.com/livarticles', ...);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Hi posit labs thanks for your reply,I tried this solution and put the URL in the script but it works but it dosen't show correctly the page that's whay I should pass by the routing :/